# Olkin and Pratt adjustment then Fisher's z calculation before meta analysing correlations from small studies?

Tags: correlation, unbiased-estimator

I have read that for small studies I need to make adjustments to the pearson correlation coefficients (r) that I extract from studies, by using the formula by Olkin and Pratt 1958, then I need to transform them using fisher's z in order to create a normal distribution, then meta -analyse, then convert back to pearson r for interpretation. Is this correct? This was in guidance by DeCoster. However I have read in the original papers that you choose Olkin and Pratt ***or*** Fishers as an adjustment, so I'm confused now about what I should be doing. Also, does the Olkin and Pratt only apply to averaged correlations, or should it be used for a single value of pearson r extracted from a single study?

Answer (score 1):

According to Alexander (1990) the Olin-Pratt estimator is not suitable for meta-analysis.

See https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/BF03334037.pdf

One should average the Fisher z transformed r values (possibly weighting them) and back-transform the averaged correlation. It might be sensible to use meta-analytic software for this (e.g., the (free) R metafor package).

Comment: This quote from the paper may be helpful: "In particular, it should not be used for other purposes in validity generalization (meta-analysis) studies since its sampling distribution suffers from the same deficiencies as does r itself. Thus, using [the Olin-Pratt estimator] or its single-sample analogue to test for homogeneity of effect sizes or to estimate variance in rs attributable to artifacts will be just as biased as using the rs themselves (Alexander et al., 1989)."

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose one of the two. Hope you have a valid reason to take a recourse to transformation. I personally do not know whether small studies legitimate a transformation of effect-sizes !. To your second question, I would say that the meta-analysis requires transformation of each effect and not that of average correlation.